# Excluding words in Conditions in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a program where I have several conditions.  I wanted to exclude a list of words (det) from a list of tokens. Up to `if len(W) <=8:`, it worked just as I wanted it to. However, I could not get the program to find any of words in det in my list of tokens, and exclude them from the printing.

This is what I have currently:

```
det = ['the','a',an','\'s']
w for w in tkV if w not in det
def BT_pos1(w):
  for w in tkV:
    if w.islower():
      if len(w) >=3:
        if len(w) <=8:
          if w not in det:
            print w, ' may be a bt.'
```

Comment: Please format code by indenting 4 spaces (press the "{ }" button on the toolbar), and use real tabs/spaces instead of `(tab)`.

Comment: What's tkV? Do you assign your generator statement to anything?

Comment: "det = ['the','a',an','\'s']" has an error after 'an' can you correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your `det` seems to be invalid (check the quotes).

If you want to check often whether an element is in a list, you can use a `set()`, which is much faster to check for content.

The whole could look like this:

```
det = set(["the", "a", "an", "'s"])

for w in tkV:
    if 3 <= len(w) <= 8 and w not in det and w.islower():
        print w, ' may be a bt.'
```

Comment: Also isLower() better to be last check.